# How can I convert this code to support MS SQL TVP bulk insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, mybatis

Currently, I am inserting values into table 'table_name' one by one. I can expect both insert and update requests for this query but during these operations, I have to take care of a condition that no same barcode will be provided to an attendee in a meeting. Now I want to change it to bulk operation using TVP approach. Could someone please help me with this?
Note - Composite key for this table is **(account_id, meeting_id, barcode)**

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table_name a
               WHERE  a.account_id = #{account_id}
                      AND a.meeting_id = #{meeting_id}
                      AND a.barcode = #{barcode})
  BEGIN
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM   table_name a
                     WHERE  a.attendee_id = #{attendee_id})
        INSERT INTO table_name
                    (account_id,
                     meeting_id,
                     barcode,
                     attendee_id)
        VALUES      ( #{account_id},
                      #{meeting_id},
                      #{barcode},
                      #{attendee_id} )
      ELSE
        UPDATE table_name
        SET    barcode = #{barcode}
        WHERE  attendee_id = #{attendee_id}
  END
```

Comment: What about a MERGE statement ?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the join condition is. You appear to assume that there is only one row per `attendee_id`, but the first `EXISTS` checks `meeting_id` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could do this with `MERGE`.

```sql
MERGE table_name t
USING @YourTVP s
  ON t.account_id = s.account_id
  AND t.meeting_id = s.meeting_id
  AND t.attendee_id = s.attendee_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
  barcode = s.barcode
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (  account_id,   meeting_id,   barcode,  attendee_id)
  VALUES (s.account_id, s.meeting_id, s.barcode,s.attendee_id)
;
```

To exclude rows which have an existing barcode, you could do the following

```sql
WITH source AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @YourTVP s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM table_name t
        WHERE t.account_id = s.account_id
          AND t.meeting_id = s.meeting_id
          AND t.barcode = s.barcode)
)
MERGE table_name t
USING source s
  ON t.account_id = s.account_id
  AND t.meeting_id = s.meeting_id
  AND t.attendee_id = s.attendee_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
  barcode = s.barcode
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (  account_id,   meeting_id,   barcode,  attendee_id)
  VALUES (s.account_id, s.meeting_id, s.barcode,s.attendee_id)
;
```

Comment: Hello Charlieface, I have updated the question with the composite key that is (account_id, meeting_id, barcode) this means I don't want the same barcode in the same meeting_id.

Comment: Then shouldn't you be updating the `attendee_id` rather than `barcode`? You need to be clear about what info you are passing in, and how you want to match it. Do we need to delete any rows?

Comment: We don't want to delete any row.

Comment: Charlie, let's assume a scenario where you created a meeting and provided a barcode to each attendee. When an ateendee arrives in your meeting you simply scan their barcode and get the details of the attendee. We need to make sure that the same barcode can not be assigned to another attendee within a meeting means within a meeting all attendees should have a unique barcode.

Comment: Suppose we want to change the barcode scanning login then we will need to update all the attendee's barcodes for that specific meeting. We don't want multiple entries for the same attendee_id within a meeting (meeting_id).

Comment: OK then you need another join condition on `attendee_id`, have edited. Note that if you wanted to delete also then you would need to pre-filter the target table using a CTE

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is only one thing left is that during insert and update how can I make sure that there is no same barcode is present for a meeting_id.

Comment: Then I think it will break down my code.

Comment: OK have modified to give you that check